# destructured state in setstate is not recognized

Tags: reactjs

Why isn't react seeing my destructured state in setstate? stateOne and stateTwo are not read in setState and are instead created as new state.

num is not inside in the destructured object.

```
onChangeTest = (e, action) => {
    const { stateOne, stateTwo } = this.state.info;
    let values = formatTest(e);
    let val0 = values[0] || '';
    let val1 = values[1] || '';
    let val2 = values[2] || '';
    let isBlur = false;

    this.setState({ num: val0, stateOne: val1, stateTwo: val2}, () => {
        this.validate(isBlur);
    });
}
```

Comment: Doesn't appear as though you are using them. What are you trying to do? You also seem to be redefining them *up* a level from `state.info.stateOne` and `state.info.stateTwo` to `state.stateOne` and `state.stateTwo` respectively.

Comment: It seems like you are assigning ```stateOne``` as ```val1``` and ```stateTwo``` as ```val2``` . You are not actually using the destructured state.

Comment: i want to set this.state.info.stateOne to val1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to merge your state update to the same level it was previously, i.e. nested in `state.info`. You still aren't using the current `state.info` values so also remove that line.

```
onChangeTest = (e, action) => {
  let values = formatTest(e);
  let val0 = values[0] || "";
  let val1 = values[1] || "";
  let val2 = values[2] || "";
  let isBlur = false;

  this.setState(
    {
      num: val0,
      info: {
        stateOne: val1,
        stateTwo: val2
      }
    },
    () => {
      this.validate(isBlur);
    }
  );
};
```

If you need to persist existing state then those need to manually merged into the nested state. A functional state update is the recommended way to do this.

```
onChangeTest = (e, action) => {
  let values = formatTest(e);
  let val0 = values[0] || "";
  let val1 = values[1] || "";
  let val2 = values[2] || "";
  let isBlur = false;

  this.setState(
    prevState => ({
      ...prevState, // <-- spread in previous state object
      num: val0,
      info: {
        ...prevState.info, // <-- spread in previous state.info object
        stateOne: val1,
        stateTwo: val2
      }
    }),
    () => {
      this.validate(isBlur);
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: how would i persist what is already in this.state.info as well?

Comment: @fosho For this you'd need to spread in the current `state.info` object. A functional state update is also the recommended pattern for this. I'll update solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear about whether you want to store state into `info` object or outside it. But still you will get an idea if you see one of the following cases.
CASE 1

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    num: "XYZ",
    stateOne: "ABCD",
    stateTwo: "EFGH"
  }
}

onChangeTest = (e, action) => {
  const { stateOne, stateTwo } = this.state;
  let values = formatTest(e);
  let val0 = values[0] || '';
  let val1 = values[1] || '';
  let val2 = values[2] || '';
  let isBlur = false;

  this.setState({ num: val0, stateOne: val1, stateTwo: val2}, () => {
    this.validate(isBlur);
  });
}
```

OR 
CASE 2

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    info: {
      num: "XYZ",
      stateOne: "ABCD",
      stateTwo: "EFGH"
    }
  }
}

onChangeTest = (e, action) => {
  const { stateOne, stateTwo } = this.state.info;
  let values = formatTest(e);
  let info = {
    num: values[0] || '',
    state1: values[1] || '',
    state2: values[2] || ''
  }

  let isBlur = false;

  this.setState({ info }, () => {
    this.validate(isBlur);
  });
}
```

and in the `onChangeTest` method, you need not have to destructure the state object if you are anyhow setting the new values to the state properties. you can remove `const { stateOne, stateTwo } = this.state.info`